# Priority Messaging in rabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am working with RabbitMQ where I am publishing the message to a retrial queue once it has failed during processing. I would want the high-priority ones to take precedence and move to the front of the queue.For me the priority of a message is to be decided by the number of times it has been retried and pushed to the retrial-queue. Recently I came across concept of message priority in RabbitMQ. But I am not gained a lot of confidence to work with it as the documentation is very brief.
I am working with multiple consumers for this queue. I want to understand how will the priority messaging working in rabbitMQ for multiple consumers.

Comment: You need to provide much more information including what you have tried and what problems you saw. Prefetch will definitely have an impact.

Comment: Some info on the matter is here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html. Pay attention to the `Interaction with consumers` section.